# Use Spring singleton-bean in prototype-beans. What would happen?

Tags: java, spring, singleton, prototype

In our system we often receive a number of user requests in one time. So we are creating prototype-beans and start proceeding the requests. 
In these prototype-beans we use of course some other beans.

So my question: **is it wise and possible to use singleton-beans in prototype-beans**? If yes, what are the conditions for proper usage?

I would think that if I make only one singleton-service to be used by a number of prototype-beans it is effective. 
However **what would happen when several beans will ask for one singleton-bean in one time**?

Comment: Thank you. Also I have found in the documentation that prototype-beans are expensive resources so they should be used only if they hold some state.

Comment: One more question. If several beans ask for one singleton-bean at one time is there any queue or all these processes will be going parallel?

Comment: Comments got a bit lengthy. I added them as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it wise and possible to use singleton-beans in prototype-beans?

It strongly depends on what your beans look like. If you store data in a singleton bean's fields you will have to think about synchronization. If your beans are totally stateless (by using a database as persistence for example), you don't need to worry about using a single instance of a bean all over the place.

However the other way around (using prototype beans in singletons) may be very risky. As there is only one instance of the singleton in the JVM, this singleton will hold a reference to the very same prototype instance for each caller. Making it statefull and subject to synchronization issues.

> What would happen when several beans will ask for one singleton-bean in one time?

An instantiated Java class is very much only a collection of data and instructions somewhere in the memory, a variable to this class holds the reference where to lookup the stuff. If a class' functions are to be executed the processor looks up the things in the memory. If there is more than one reference to the same class, this means that the same memory address is referenced multiple times. The JVM manages memory access and guarantees compliance to the [Java Memory Model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_memory_model). This is something you should be aware of, but is usually not that important for your day-to-day business - unless you implement the JVM of course :-)